# Django views.py file argument passing

Tags: django

I am using Django 2.0.6. My folder structure is like this:

```
mysite
    mysite
    polls 
        templates
            polls
                index.html
                choice.html
```

Please consider that all the other files are present. I am not mentioning them here. I have designed a URL in the format of 'polls/question/choice'. Here question is a variable which I am passing as a argument. Now I have designed a Question class in models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def recent_publish(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Now I have pointed my url mapping like this in `polls/urls.py`:

```
path('<str:ques>/choice/',views.choice,name='choice')
```

And in the views file my choice function is like this

```
def choice(request,ques):
    for q in  Question.objects.all():
        if q.question_text == ques:
            break

    return render(request,'polls/choice.html',{'q':q})
```

So here I am passing q which is a object of Question class to choice.html

Now here is choice.html

```
{% for e in q.choice_set.all() %}
    <h1>{{e}}</h1>enter code here
```

And this is error I am getting

```
In template C:\Users\Nik\Desktop\mysite\polls\templates\polls\choice.html, 
error at line 1

Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'q.choice_set.all()'
1   {% for e in q.choice_set.all() %}
2       <h1>{{e}}</h1>
```

Is my syntax wrong or something else?

Comment: It should be `q.choice_set.all` in template language. And they deliberately did that to actually prevent people like you to write business logic in the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template does not allow method calls (and definitely not with parameters). This has been done deliberately, to prevent programmers to write *business logic* in a template.

You *can* of course write this like:

```
{% for e in q.choice_set.all %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Since Django templates automatically call a callable (notice that there are no brackets). But I would advise you to define something on the *models* layer for this.

You can boost the search further, by performing this at the database level, with:

```
def choice(request,ques):
    q = Question.objects.filter(question_text=ques).first()
    return render(request,'polls/choice.html',{'q':q})
```

Comment: so do you mean that    q = Question.objects.filter(question_text=ques).first()   is faster than a for loop like this   for q in  Question.objects.all():
        if q.question_text == ques:
            break                   as I have done above

Comment: @NikhilRathore: well do you know why we store data in a database, and not just in a file managed by Python? A database (a) typically works with indexes, and (b) has algorithms to work with huge amounts of data. Typically a database outperforms Python by a factor 100, 1000, or even 10k+. We furthermore reduce the amount of overhead of communication, and the database manager is closer to the data.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Got it know.

Comment: I have one more doubt and it is not possible to ask here so I am asking a new one

Comment: @NikhilRathore: if it is quite related to this question, you can ask, otherwise it is better to ask a separate question.

Comment: Well it is related to django but is different from this. Anyways this is the link to the question    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123041/django-removing-hardcoded-urls-in-templates