# django Removing hardcoded URLs in templates

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

I know that in a template file I can include this code which will return a list of links

```
{% for q in all %}
    <ul>
        <li><a href={% url 'detail' q.id %}>{{ q.question_text }}</a></li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Now django will search for the name `'detail'` in the `urls.py` file of my app directory and it will automatically give the value of `q.id` to that argument. But what if I have a url that contains more than 1 variable. So here I can only give one argument i.e, `q.id`. But what if I want to give more than one argument.
Hope I am clear

Answer (score 5):

Well you can see the `urls.py` as a declaration of how URLs map to view functions (and class-based views). A url can have an arbitrary number of parameters.

If we have for example the following URL:

```
    url(r'^detail/(?P<year>(\d+))/(?P<name>(\w+))/$', views.detail),
```

We can see this url as some sort of virtual function that would take parameters like:

```
def some_url(year, name):
    # ...
    pass
```

So we can construct this URL with *unnamed parameters*:

```
{% url 'detail' 1981 q.name %}
```

or with *named* parameters:

```
{% url 'detail' name=q.name year=1981 %}
```

Comment: The reason we use this kind of notation, as I read from the official documentation is that  we don't have to alter all over urls in case we want to change any url. We can just update in the urls.py file in the app directory. Django will automatically match the value given in  {% url 'detail' q.id %} with the argument in the url.py file.  But here you are assigning in the url template. Now if I want to change name to surname than I would have to update that in urls.py as well as here in the template file.

Comment: If suppose there was only one argument then if I wanted to change the url format I could have easily changed that in the urls.py file and that would work. Also I am using django 2.0.6 which doesn't use the regular expressions

Comment: Well the unnamed parameters have as advantage that if you change the name of the parameter, no changes have to be made to the `{% url ...%}`s, but in case you change the order, you have to change them. If you later want to change the *order* you better use named parameters. Point is that typically changing the *parameters* of a URL does not happen often, since this is not visible to users.

Comment: Well it is working both ways. Thank you for helping me.